# Как заменить запятую через jquery, только в том случае если перед запятой нету ничего?

Tags: jquery, json

Вывожу через json данные, и некоторые данные выходят в формате ,06   а надо чтобы было 0,06
Вывод моих данных

```
for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    tr = $('<tr/>');
    tr.append("<td>" + json[i].DATE1 + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + json[i].ITOGO + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + json[i].POSTUPL + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + json[i].PREM + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + json[i].PVU + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + json[i].PROCH + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + json[i].VYPLATY + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + json[i].INK + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + json[i].SPIS + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + json[i].VYPL + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + json[i].KOMISS + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + json[i].STRVYPL + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + json[i].PROCHIE + "</td>");
       $('table').first().append(tr);
}
```

пытался так

```
tr.append("<td>" + json[i].POSTUPL.replace(/,/g, '0,') + "</td>");
```

но по логике он бы все запятые поменял бы, но даже так не получилось

Comment: Раз запятая это первый символ, то используйте `^` перед ней. Что будет означать начало строки.

Comment: "Дорогие товарищи ученые. У меня не меняется текст. Какой текст у меня не меняется, догадайтесь сами."

Comment: @Igor Почему вы постоянно отвечаете в таком тоне? я понимаю что иногда мои вопросы взрывают мозг. Но разве по тексту не понятно что у меня все данные выводятся в цифрах, соответственно я везде должен его поменять, так же указал как я пытался решить свою проблему, не получилось и прошу помощи и совета тут

Comment: Возможно, там другой какой-то символ, который выглядит как запятая, но фактически это другой символ?